# Vim - :set background=<expression>

Tags: vim

I am trying to make a leader-mapping for toggling between `bg=dark` and `bg=light`, but I am having trouble. Vim doesn't seem to like things like this:

```
:set bg=(&bg=='dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')
```

It sees the spaces as separators. I've removed the spaces and messed around with `eval()` but with no success.

Is there a way to set an option to the result of an expression in Vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use expressions in the `:set` command; only basic string/numeric values.

Use `:let` instead. You can refer to setting variables by prefixing the name with `&`. Converted to that, it would read:

```
:let &background = (&background == 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')
```

You can also use the short-hand values such as `&bg` if you prefer; but for vimrc stuff I recommend using the longer variants, as it will be a lot clearer what that means in five year's time from now (people's vimrc files tend to last a long time!)

This also allows you to use slightly more relaxed spacing, as `:set` is rather sensitive about that.

For the Vim docs on this, see [`:help :set-args`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3aset%2dargs) and [`:help :let-&`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3alet%2d%26).

Comment: Thanks, just beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can use expressions with `:set`, but you can with `:let`:

```
nnoremap <Leader>b :let &bg=(&bg=='dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')<Enter>
```

Comment: Note that you almost always want to use `nnoremap` instead of `nmap` for non-recursive mappings. Read [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to understand that earlier and having trouble.